# Warning in caret glm model - prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

Tags: generalized-linear-model, caret

I’m trying to use caret for glm model:

```
lrFit <- train(IsPrematureBirth ~ .,
data = training, 
method = "glm",
trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 5))
```

However it returns warning like:

> In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type
>   ==  ... :   prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

I understand the dummy variable trap, or perfect collinearity. From

```
lrFit$finalModel
```

I can see coefficient of one predictor named IsIvf is NA. IsIvf is a dichotomous predictor with levels 0 and 1. If I remove that predictor IsIvf, the warning is gone.

```
table(training$IsIvf)
    0           1  
    1906        667
```

str(training)

```
 'data.frame':  2573 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ InseminationTypeName.HALF      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ InseminationTypeName.ICSI      : num  1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ InseminationTypeName.IVF       : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ InfertilityTypeName.X          : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ InfertilityTypeName.Y          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ Age                            : int  34 40 37 32 34 37 29 30 32 39 ...
 $ PreganancyCount                : int  3 2 3 4 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ DeliveryCount                  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GestationalAge                 : num  38.4 41.1 39 37.4 41.1 ...
 $ IsIvf                          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ IsTubalInfertility             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ IsFemaleInfertility            : int  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ HasPregnanceInducedHypertension: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HasGestationalDiabetes         : int  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ HasAnemia                      : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ HasPrematureRuptureOfMembranes : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ HasPostpartumHemorrhage        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ HasPlacentaPrevia              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ IsPrematureBirth               : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The distribution of IsIvf is:

```
Row [1 … 174]: all 1s. 
Row [175…868]: all 0s. 
Row [869 … 1362]: all 1s:
Row [1363…2573]: all 0s.
```

Switch rows, reduce the number of trainControl from 10 to 2 cannot fix the warning.

If I deliberately randomly force IsIvf on 2 rows (say 1180 and 1185) in 1s group to 0:

```
training[1180, 10] = 0
training[1185, 10] = 0
```

Then the warnings are gone.

Can anybody help to explain this?

Comment: It is most likely some linear combination between a few variables. The `caret` function `findLinearCombos` might help identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, I run findLinearCombos and found IsIvf = sum of another 2 dummified predictors. I need to check the business meaning behind this.

Comment: This question might be help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26560328/3101585